# How to print the current time and the number of executions in a custom syscall?

Tags: linux, unix, system-calls, time.h

This should be written to the kernel log:

```
Hello world!
This is (number) time that you use the system call today
Current time is : (time)
```

I'm trying to use `linux/time.h` but I don't know how it works.
Can anyone give me an example? Should I do something like this?

```
#include<linux/linkage.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/sched.h>
#include<linux/time.h>

asmlinkage long sys_mycall (int someVal)
{
    time_t t;
    time(&t);

    printk("myInt: %d", someVal);
    printk("%s", ctime(&t)) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: can you post your code/logic?

Comment: What doesn't work about the code you've included?